# Firebase functions api blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have some firebase cloud functions that I call from a React application. Localhost to localhost works fine, but when I try to contact the deployed version of the cloud functions (both from my localhost and from my deployed React app) I get a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here's the functions `index.js`:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require('cors');
const app = require("express")();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

const {
  signup,
  login,
  loginAdmin,
  getUserData,
} = require("./handlers/users");

...
app.post("/login", login);
....
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Here's the what I try to add to the login function:

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*"); // added this line
  // actual function is irrelevant
```

but it didn't work, so I also tried this:

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  console.log('outside')
  return await cors(req, res, async () => {
    console.log('inside')
    // function code....
```

But in this case the function hangs, from the console I can see that it prints `outside` but not `inside`.

The front-end code is the same so I doubt the problem is in there...

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

Thanks to the answers I added this line of code in `index.js`:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require('cors');
const app = require("express")();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.options('/login', cors()) // <- this one

const {
  signup,
  login,
  loginAdmin,
  getUserData,
} = require("./handlers/users");

...
app.post("/login", login);
....
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Still no luck, I deployed again but I have the same error.

Comment: CORS is part of the official documentation, including pre-flight CORS... -> https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

> preflight request

which, as [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) is an OPTIONS request.

You are only binding your code which sets `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to a handler for a POST request.

The [documentation for the `cors` module](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight) you are using, explains how to set code up for a pre-flight request.

One example is:

> ```
> app.options('/products/:id', cors()) // enable pre-flight request for DELETE request
> ```